# Entity Framework query returns one record, but its supposed to return more

Tags: entity-framework, entity-relationship, dbcontext

As title say, i got problem with a query in Asp.net mvc 3 EF. 
I got 2 tables with 1 to many relationship.

table1 Users int user_ID string username

table2 Friends int friendshipID int user_ID int friend_ID

The controller:

// // GET: /User/Details/5

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
    {
        User user = db.Users.Include("Friends").FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_ID == id);
        //Also for each friend get the User:
        foreach (var friend in user.Friends.ToList())
        {
            friend.User = db.Users.Find(friend.friend_ID);
        }
        return View(user);
    }
```

The view "details":

```
@model Social2.Models.User

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Details";
}

<h2>Details</h2>
    <div class="display-field">
        @foreach (var friend in @Model.Friends)
    {
           @friend.User.username;
    }   
    </div>
```

Context:

```
public partial class ASPNETDBEntities : DbContext
{
    public ASPNETDBEntities()
        : base("name=ASPNETDBEntities")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }

    public DbSet<aspnet_Users> aspnet_Users { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
    public DbSet<User> Users { get; set; }
}
```

user model:

```
public partial class User
{
    public User()
    {
        this.Friends = new HashSet<Friend>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int user_ID { get; set; }
    public System.Guid user_UniqueID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }

    public virtual aspnet_Users aspnet_Users { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Friend> Friends { get; set; }
}
```

friend model

```
public partial class Friend
{
    public int friendship_ID { get; set; }
    public int user_fr_ID { get; set; }
    public int friend_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

The problem is, when i go to ~/user/details/1, the view show only one(the last one) friend.For every user it shows their last friend. How to show them all ?

Comment: You can btw use `Include("Friends.User")` instead of the loop. But that won't solve your problem. Did you check in the database that you really have multiple friends for the given user?

Comment: Yes, i deleted the last friend of the first user, added new, and now it shows him on the page..

Comment: Well, this doesn't prove that you have multiple friends for a user. I meant: If you have a user with Id = 5, do you have multiple records in the Friend table which all have the value 5 in column `user_fr_ID`?

Comment: i got 4 users and database look like this:

1 2 |
1 3 |
2 3 |
1 4 |
3 1 |
each 2 numbers are one row

Comment: and i am checking for user with id 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database must have *two* relationships defined like so:

[image: DB Schema]

If you create an Entity Model from this schema you also get two one-to-many relationships. And when you apply the DBContext T4 template to this model you should get POCO classes like so:

```
public partial class Users
{
    public Users()
    {
        this.Friends = new HashSet<Friends>();
        this.Friends1 = new HashSet<Friends>();
    }

    public int user_ID { get; set; }
    public string username { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Friends> Friends { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Friends> Friends1 { get; set; }
}

public partial class Friends
{
    public int friendship_ID { get; set; }
    public int user_fr_ID { get; set; }
    public int friend_ID { get; set; }

    public virtual Users Users { get; set; }
    public virtual Users Users1 { get; set; }
}
```

`Users.Friends` and `Friends.Users` form a pair for the first relationship and `Users.Friends1` and `Friends.Users1` are a pair for the second relationship. (You can rename the navigation properties in the model designer to make the names more meaningful.) Your query would look like this then (you can include a "second level" and don't need the loop as you did in your example):

```
public ViewResult Details(int id)
{
    // important to use User1 in Include, not User
    User user = db.Users.Include("Friends.User1")
        .FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_ID == id);
    return View(user);
}
```

With `DbContext` you can also use the strongly typed version of `Include`:

```
Include(u => u.Friends.Select(f => f.User1))
```

Comment: Ty for your time and help. I will recreate the database. One more thing, do u know any online tutorials or something similar for this queries in EF ? I mean for the ".Include()" or ".FirstOrDefault()" and some similar functions. I really dont know what they do and i really want to learn them.

Comment: @MilanMilanovski: Here is a (12-part) tutorial about `DbContext` in general: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2011/01/27/using-dbcontext-in-ef-feature-ctp5-part-1-introduction-and-model.aspx. Part 6 contains `Include`. For `FirstOrDefault` and so on... any LINQ tutorial is fine. Most of the LINQ methods work with EF, only a few don't. Pluralsight (http://www.pluralsight-training.net) has a lot of training videos about LINQ and EF as well. (Their LINQ course is awesome.) They offer a free trial, so you can test before you decide to subscribe or not.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here

```
User user = db.Users.Include("Friends").FirstOrDefault(u => u.user_ID == id);
```

`FirstOrDefault` gives only one record.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is mapping of the class Friend.

try change to:

```
public partial class Friend
{
    [Key]
    public int friendship_ID { get; set; }
    public int user_fr_ID { get; set; }
    public int friend_ID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("friend_ID")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: friend_id is the foreign key ? If not, just chang the parameter.

Comment: I think ill recreate the database, damn names, i didnt knew that it name+ID should be in same word

Comment: @MilanMilanovski: Do you use Model-First or Database-First? I guess it because of the `UnintentionalCodeFirstException`. In this case the data annotations don't have any effect because the mapping is defined in EDMX and not with Code-First annotations or Fluent API.

Comment: i use database first. Dont tell me that data annotations dont have effect......... i spend whole day trying to figure out the problem..

Comment: @MilanMilanovski: No, annotations (for EF mapping) have no effect with DB First. They are only for Code-First. What did you do with the code autogenerated by the DbContext T4 template? You are not supposed to change this code at all. Can you show the original autogenerated code before you changed it? Most likely the relationships are wrong...

Comment: I know that i shouldnt make changes, i didnt make any change except the ones in this answer, so the models are the originals in the question

Comment: @MilanMilanovski: But where does the `[Key]` attribute in your question come from? The T4 template doesn't generate any attribute. Anyway, if only those two navigation properties `User.Friends` and `Friend.User` have been created, EF "thinks" they are a pair for the same relationship. But this is wrong, you must have *two* relationships, i.e. there should be *two pairs* of navigation properties. Are *both* columns `user_fr_ID` and `friend_ID` in the `Friends` table foreign keys to the `User` table with a separate FK constraint for each?

Comment: Hmm never though of this, no, just user_fr_ID is foreign key to the User table